# Checking the pattern containing numeric values, comma, space and colon in Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string in c#, say str. Using regex, how can I check if it matches the format 'n, To: n'.
  Here n is a numeric value between 0 and 4999.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers need not be same:

```
([0-4]?\d{1,3}) To:([0-4]?\d{1,3})
```

If the numbers need to be the same; your pattern will be:

```
([0-4]?\d{1,3}) To:\1
```

Comment: @user3876348 You can mark this post as selected answer. It will not appear under unsolved questions afterwards :)